# remove applied migrations with --force

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework Core, just a question on remove applied migrations with --force, because I'm confused by the display message in the shell window.

So Let's say I create a class with some properties. then I add a new property, then add a migration and update to this migration so that the table in the database had a new column. Then I removed this already applied migration

> dotnet ef migrations remove --force

and the display message is sth like this:

> Removing migration '_AddNewProperty' without checking the database. If this migration has been applied to the database, you will need to manually reverse the changes it made.
>   Removing migration '_AddNewProperty'.
>   Reverting model snapshot.

so the keywords **without checking the database** seems to indicates that only the migration.cs file is deleted, EF won't bother to make any changes to the table in the database (downgrade to previous migration state by calling deleted migration's Down() method) and **you will need to manually reverse the changes it made** indicates that I need to delete the new column in the table by myself.

But after I removed the applied migration, the underlying table in the dababase also get updated(new column is automatically removed by EF), so what does  "without checking the database" and " manually reverse the changes it made" really mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the message you posted exist in EF Core 2.0, you can check it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.0/src/EFCore.Design/Properties/DesignStrings.resx) (name = "ForceRemoveMigration"). If you change the branch to release/2.1 and newer you will notice the message has been changed to

> Unable to check if the migration '{name}' has been applied to the database. If it has, you will need to manually reverse the changes it made. Error encountered while checking: {error}

So I think the message was misleading and finally changed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the new message still says you will need to manually  reverse the changed it made, but EF actually reverse the changes automatically

Comment: @secondimage If you look at [MigrationsScaffolder.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/105a2c1a5b962e65d27e40f7db55bab131c4af77/src/EFCore.Design/Migrations/Design/MigrationsScaffolder.cs) on lines 256-261 you will notice that this message appear only if exception is caught and force is set to true.

Comment: Looking at that same file in [branch release/2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.0/src/EFCore.Design/Migrations/Design/MigrationsScaffolder.cs) we can see that ```ForceRemoveMigration``` appears every time "force" is set.

Comment: so you mean if I use 2.1 version, and use --force, there won't be any message if everything is OK with no exceptions, will try it when I home today

Comment: @secondimage yep, that's the way it should work on ef core 2.1 and newer

Comment: Could you also take a look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641888/how-to-combine-both-of-code-first-and-database-first-approaches