# Update DbContext file with new table - asp.net core DB first approch

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created project in asp.net core 2.0 and created DbContext using command line (dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold .... ) to generate Context. Now i had create new table in SQL server.
How i can update my existing DbContext using command line with new table.

Comment: Run `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` again.

Comment: Now that you have generated the DB Context for your system, I think you can switch to EF Code first approach which is more convenient. Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641888/how-to-combine-both-of-code-first-and-database-first-approaches/57643595#57643595